# ssrs shows errors after subreport in maIn report

Tags: reporting-services, subreport

I have a simple main report and a subreport.   The subreport uses two parameters which I set up by selecting the values from the drop downs on the parameters screen.  The main report contains one set of patient information in several tables in a list.  The subreport contains additional details that run off a different data set.

When I run the main report, the subreport runs correctly except that after the last record, there is a repeating error message: "One or more parameters were not specified for the subreport, [Subreport Name] Sub Report.  This number of times this message repeats before the next record in the main report varies from patient to patient.

I have validated what's being returned in the subreport when the main report is run by running the sub report separately.  The sub report correctly shows all of the data for each patient.  Nothing is missing.

I checked that none of the parameters had a list of available values or default values.

I experimented with hardcoding the values passed to the subreport and this resulted in no error messages displaying.

Scratching my head over this one.

Comment: This is really hard to debug w/o the code, data structure, and data.  Basically, you're on your own and have to dig into your data problem.  Unfortunately, you're the only one who can fix your problem.  Maybe a null value?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was using a table object and putting the subreport in the detail row. I tried using the same grouping as the list but it still returned multiple records.

I deleted the table and replaced it with a matrix. This resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning exact number of parameters from your main report to your subreport. Like you have defined more parameters in subreport properties and they are not returning from main report